# American English SMS Text Message Corpora

Tags: language, corpora, english

I'm seeking corpora of American English SMS (<=160 characters) text messages. What corpora are available?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The largest English corpus I've found (over 10,000 messages) is the [National University of Singapore's SMS corpus](https://doi.org/10.25540/WVM0-4RNX) -- select the corpus with "all" messages -- however, [closer examination](http://wing.comp.nus.edu.sg:8080/SMSCorpus/statistic.jsp) reveals that relatively few of the messages originate from US participants.

[A corpus of SMS spam messages](http://www.esi.uem.es/~jmgomez/smsspamcorpus/) has been created which are written in English. There are over 1,000 legitimate messages and only a few hundred are spam-related.

Dr. Caroline Tagg created a corpus of SMS messages (although I believe they are primarily in British English), but I cannot find the corpus online. However, [her paper](http://etheses.bham.ac.uk/253/1/Tagg09PhD.pdf) contains hundreds of messages from the corpus.

I created a [text message corpus of SMS messages in American English](https://web.archive.org/web/20130921043042/http://cybersecurity.cit.purduecal.edu/content/tmcorpus.html) that contains over 4,900 messages, a few hundred of which are related to illegal drug use. [Now available only on archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20130921043042/http://cybersecurity.cit.purduecal.edu/content/tmcorpus.html).

Answer (score 3):

I recently made a corpus available of text messages from Spanish-dominant bilingual young adults in New York City (Bilingual Youth Texts Corpus). It is at [www.byts.commons.gc.cuny.edu](http://byts.commons.gc.cuny.edu/)