# Text message corpus for American english

Tags: data-request, language, english, corpora

I am doing a research project to identify some patterns in how people interact with each other using text messages. The scope of the project is confined to American users. Can someone suggest a good place to find a corpus for American SMS/text messages for my experiment?

I know that NUS Singapore has an SMS corpus, but on careful observation, I realized that the messages in that corpus do not generate from American users.

Comment: Don't know how I missed this when first posted -- don't have time to verify if this is the right paper, but try : http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~kanmy/papers/smsCorpus.pdf ; http://wing.comp.nus.edu.sg/SMSCorpus/

Comment: And here, too: http://www.infochimps.com/datasets/text-messages-sent-on-9112001-wikileaksorg

Comment: One more: http://www.infochimps.com/datasets/uber-anonymized-gps-logs

Comment: possible duplicate of [American English SMS Text Message Corpora](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/165/american-english-sms-text-message-corpora)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know a corpus, but I know a way to create one. If you know how to program you can use the Facebook API and download all the public facebook status from USA with their comments. Then you can use them as a corpus.

Info about [Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/)